# extract data from lotus notes to sql server

Tags: sql, lotus

while trying to extract data from lotus notes to sql server 2016
i am getting error like this
 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding., Connector 'sql16'
do you guys have any idea about this?